# Unable to change or disable Checkstyle in Gradle build

Tags: android, build.gradle, checkstyle

I have a project which has had checkstyle configured and working for a long time, but now it's suddenly complaining of

```
[ant:checkstyle] C:\foo.java:23: Missing a Javadoc comment.
```

for every file.

It's correct that we are missing it, but the rules weren't supposed to be checking that and previously hadn't been.

Checked and tried:

- Tried re-configuring the "Javadoc" modules in checkstyle.xml, but it get's automatically overwritten as soon as I attempt to build again.
- Deleting the whole config directory containing the checkstyle.xml file, and it get's automatically recreated.
- Verified there is absolutely no reference to checkstyle in the build.gradle file
- Tried specifically including a blank checkstyle field to build.gradle, still same error

> ```
> checkstyle {
>     sourceSets = []
> }
> ```

What could I be missing?

Using **Android Studio 1.4 - 1.5.1**

Comment: Are you getting the same error when Gradle is run from the command line? Which Checkstyle version are you using?

Comment: Yes a "gradle build" from command line attempts the same checks. I'm not sure how to check what Checkstyle version I'm using, since I can't find where in the configuration it's being set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Though I wasn't directly including checkstyle, I had a line

```
apply from: 'http://apps.tapadoo.com/quality/quality.gradle'
```

which contains all the lint configuration, including checkstyle.